# I downloaded a project from server but the images are not showing with correct path

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

I downloaded a project from server, it's using part Laravel + part plain HTML. 
The image tag below :-

```
<a href="{{ HTTP_SERVER }}"><img id="header-logo-image" src="{{ DIR_FILES.'logo/'.$setting->Logo }}" />
```

When I inspect element on the image and right click , open image in new tab, I get
http://localhost/project1/files/logo/logo.png 
It shows object not found.

However if I open a new tab in the browser, and put in the URL http://localhost/project1/files/logo/logo.png , the image appears.

UPDATE :

I'm using XAMPP. I created a test file, place it in root dir and insert a simple  and another  . Both able to display the image. Only the file under layouts/_header.blade.php unable to display the image.

Any advise why it's not appearing when view from the project? 
Thanks

Comment: In the sources tab, check whether the image is loaded or not. If not, navigate to networks tab and reload the page to see what's the response while requesting the image.

Comment: @SagarV thanks for your reply. I get error 404 for the image when I navigate to networks tab.

Comment: Try copy pasting the url instead of retype it to see if there are any invisible characters.

Comment: @user202729 I tried, the URL came out is exactly http://localhost/project1/files/logo/logo.png .. thus I'm confused as well why it is not displaying when access from the website.

Comment: How are you accessing your page? AS in, what is the URL in the browser?

Comment: @2pha I access it via "http://localhost/project1". I'm using XAMPP. I created a test file, and insert a simple <img src='files/logo/logo.png'> and another  <img src='http://localhost/project1/files/logo/logo.png'>  . Both able to display the image. Only the file under layouts/_header.blade.php  unable to display the image.

Comment: Recheck the code whether it contains any space or other charachters. Especially space at the end. If not, Share a screenshot of networks tab.

Comment: @SagarV Thanks for your help ! The answer below helped me to solve it !

Comment: fyi, if the issue is not with space, you can put `http://` before the image url because, when directly entered in browser address bar, it'll treat localhost as a host but when requested from the page without the protocol, browser may treat localhost as a directory resides within the host. Without seeing it, we can't say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="{{url('/')}}" class="scrollto">
<img src="{{url('/img/logo.png')}} "title=" Logo"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Managed to display the image using this.